# How to auto hide the tab bar when presenting other view

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

Is there anybody used the IM software called QQ (popular in China)? This software has an tab bar and it has 5 tabs. In each tab there is a navigation controller, like this:

[image: main UI of QQ]

In the second tab when tap any of the first three table view cell this tab's view will transit to an other view in normal way, that is the transition happen within the tab bar controller.

[image: transition to other view in normal way]

When tap any of the last three table view cell this tab's view will also transit to an other view but meanwhile the tab bar will transit together with the view controller too.

[image: transition to other view with tab bar]

This is very strange! According to the first situation we can guess that the navigation controller is the child of the tab bar controller, but according to the second situation the tab bar may be the child of navigation controller, right? Anybody knows how to implement this UI? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks god! The answer is set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property of the view controller pushed into navigation controller stack to YES.

Answer (score 0):

The tab bar in the screenshot doesn't have to be a tab bar, it could be a custom view on the view controller, I've used a similar approach when the tab bar needed to change drastically.

Comment: Maybe you are right! But what is the relationship between the tab bar and the view controllers below? parent-child or sibling? And how to transit the tab bar out with the view controller?

Comment: The tab bar isn't being transitioned out with the view controller, the UIView that looks like a tabbar is being transitioned out.  If we forget about the tabbar for a second, and just assume the navigation controllers are being directly manipulated by the button pressed on our uiview that looks like a tabbar (that actually belongs to the viewcontroller).

Comment: It's my fault! I forgot to correct my words. I know the tab bar is not a real tab bar, it just a custom view, right? So, could you please re-read the first comment again? I have update it. Sorry, I found that I can't edit it now!

What I want to know is that how to transit the so called tab bar out together with the view controller when the view controller is pushed into the navigation controller?

Comment: In the most basic implementation, the tab bar doesn't need to exist. They could be using a single UINavigationController, which pushes and pops view controllers utilising: `pushViewController:animated:`, `popViewControllerAnimated:`, and `popToViewController:animated:`.  They wouldn't need to retain references to the view controllers (to use the `popToViewController:animated:`) that they want to act like the tab bars root view controllers, because you could just inspect the UINavigationControllers viewControllers property and pull the instance from there. I hope this is understandable ;p

Comment: Apologies, I've just re-checked the screenshots, the custom tab bar view can be on the UIWindow.  There's also another way they could be doing this, using a UITabBar, and something similar to the functionality that [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController) provides.

Comment: Sorry for disturb you again! Look at the third picture I have post in the question. In the picture we can see that the tab bar(custom view) is transited out together with the view controller below it. So, how to move the tab bar out when pushed the view controller into the navigation controller?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27875/discussion-between-user352891-and-kery)